# Jsp Action Form

Tags: servlets, jsp-tags

Here is the jsp code:

```
<form name="loginForm" action="<%=formUrl%>" autocomplete="off" method="POST" >
...
</form>
```

What does **<%=formUrl%>** mean?Is it refers to servlet name? I dont have servlet named **formUrl**.

Comment: `formUrl` is a java variable, `<%=%>` is expression tag which is supposed to print out value of given expression.

Comment: Thanks Aravind.I have another doubt.   String formUrl="Portal/conversionRouter.do"   What does it mean?

Comment: `Portal/conversionRouter.do` it seems to value of `url-pattern` of the given servlet. You may check the `web.xml` or servlet's java class for match